# Use Tailwind css in a nrwl/nx Next js project

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, nrwl-nx

How to make Tailwind css work in a nrwl/nx Next js project?
Now I am using the common approach but it failed:

```
[ error ] ./styles/main.css
Error: Didn't get a result from child compiler
```

the common approach I took:

1. `npx create-nx-workspace@latest my-org`
2. `yarn add --dev @nrwl/next`
3. `nx g @nrwl/next:application my-project`
4. `yarn add tailwindcss autoprefixer postcss-loader @zeit/next-css`
5. `cd apps/my-project`
6. create

```
postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer')
  ]
};
```

7. create

```
next.config.js
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
module.exports = withCSS({});
```

8. create

```
styles/main.css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

9. create a default _app.js in pages
10. add import '../styles/main.css' in _app.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem.
Here is how I added tailwind in next.js project

1. install `tailwind` and `autoprefixer` in the workspace
2. create `tailwind.config.js` and `tailwind.css`.
3. import `tailwind.css` at `_app.tsx`
4. create `next.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  webpack: config => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: {
            ident: 'postcss',
            plugins: [
              require('tailwindcss')(
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'tailwind.config.js') // the absolute path of your tailwind.config.js
              ),
              require('autoprefixer')
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      // the absolute path of the folder contains tailwind.css
      // I reuse tailwind.css across projects and libs so I put it in the workspace root
      // Maybe I should create a lib for it.
      include: path.resolve('./global') 
    });

    return config;
  }
};
```

It is similar if you wanna integrate Tailwind with lib's storybook or in projects of other framework. Just find the way to push rules to webpack config.

Hope it helps.

Comment: hey @Yan thank you for posting the steps. I am trying to follow these steps and get this compile error
```
error - ./pages/index.module.css 11:5
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:5)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ../../node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|  */
| 
> html {
|   line-height: 1.15; /* 1 */
|   -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
```
any tips please? thanks

Comment: Hey @jerry it seems the issue is on css module. I did not use that, and btw I do not use nx for monorepo management now, so not quite sure how to properly config it. You can check nx's git issues. I remember there are some discussion on this there and they might have support css module since then.

Answer (score 0):

If you use new version - 9.2 then you need this article:

https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-2

And updated setup example for Next.js 9.2:

https://github.com/tailwindcss/setup-examples/pull/50

I tried it, it good works for me.

Comment: Thanks. But here the context is within a nrwl/nx workspace. Have you tried in it?